# RHEL7 wireless configuration not available

Tags: wifi, rhel7

I'm trying to use a wireless USB key on a RHEL7 NUC.  The adapter shows up in 'ifconfig':

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.21  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::baae:edff:fe7d:ce5a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:ae:ed:7d:ce:5a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
...

enp0s20f0u3: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::214:d1ff:fed8:cc0f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:14:d1:d8:cc:0f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
...
```

but there is no wireless configuration options available in NetworkManager, so I'm not able to select an SSID/wpa2-password and so forth.

I found a [thread that discussed a similar issue](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=8205) for centos.  Following advice there, it appeared that I did not have the kernel module loaded for the wireless adapter:

```
# lspci -nn | grep -i net

00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I219-V [8086:1570] (rev 21)
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)

# grep -i 8086 /lib/modules/*/modules.alias | grep -i 24f3 | tee -a q
alias pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00000010bc*sc*i* iwlwifi

# grep -i 8086 /lib/modules/*/modules.alias | grep -i 1570
alias pci:v00008086d00001570sv*sd*bc*sc*i* e1000e

# lsmod | grep wifi
# (NOTHING)

# modprobe iwlwifi
# lsmod | grep wifi
iwlwifi               112501  0 
cfg80211              514740  1 iwlwifi
```

However after following the advice in that thread for restarting the NetworkManager:

```
# service network stop
# service wpa_supplicant stop
# chkconfig --level 12345 network off
# chkconfig --level 12345 wpa_supplicant off
# chkconfig --level 2345 NetworkManager on
# service NetworkManager restart
```

there are no still no wireless configuration options showing in NetworkManager.  I do have the NetworkManager-wifi package installed:

```
# rpm -qa | grep NetworkM
NetworkManager-config-server-1.0.0-16.git20150121.b4ea599c.el7_1.x86_64
NetworkManager-libreswan-0.9.8.0-5.el7.x86_64
NetworkManager-libnm-1.0.0-16.git20150121.b4ea599c.el7_1.x86_64
NetworkManager-glib-1.0.0-16.git20150121.b4ea599c.el7_1.x86_64
NetworkManager-wifi-1.0.0-16.git20150121.b4ea599c.el7_1.x86_64
NetworkManager-team-1.0.0-16.git20150121.b4ea599c.el7_1.x86_64
NetworkManager-openvpn-0.9.8.2-4.el7.1.x86_64
NetworkManager-openvpn-gnome-0.9.8.2-4.el7.1.x86_64
NetworkManager-tui-1.0.0-16.git20150121.b4ea599c.el7_1.x86_64
NetworkManager-1.0.0-16.git20150121.b4ea599c.el7_1.x86_60
```

What else do I need to do to make the wifi adapter available to NetworkManager.  Or, perhaps simpler, how can I configure the wireless adapter on the command line?

Comment: Why does your server need wireless connectivity?

Comment: It's temporary.  I need to fish some wires into the room it will live.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that a [newer than 3.10 kernel as well as updated firmware was required](http://peeterjoot.com/2016/04/26/configuring-wireless-on-a-rhel7-nuc6i5syh/).

Comment: If you were able to get it working with a newer kernel, you should open a case with Red Hat so that they can fix the problem.